# Question closed as duplicate, pointing to "learn the tech" question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, moderation

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33960787/regex-to-not-not-match-exactly-against-a-list?noredirect=1#comment55679341_33960787) was marked as duplicate.

The person closing it simply points at a question on "how to learn regular expressions".

This is not a simple question. The closest answer so far uses negative lookaheads and `\b`. By that measure, nearly all questions on Stackoverflow would be dupes. Closing this as a duplicate with *that* link is just rude.

The real frustrating thing is after playing around with the ideas in the top answer I now **do** have the full real answer but I can't answer it for other people who might have this question in the future, because the mod got trigger happy.

Comment: Vote to reopen?

Comment: Yeah @DavidPostill I did but what on earth was the mod even thinking? The only time that should ever be an appropriate dupe is when someone is asking "how do I learn regex?" Even basic questions like `what does `.` mean in regex` shouldn't be a duplicate of that.

Comment: Closing your question as a duplicate of an old, closed, locked, far too broad question does not strike me as productive. Voting to reopen. Also note that it was a 56K-rep user that dupe-hammered your question, not a diamond moderator.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer It wasn't a moderator, it was a community user that had the gold close privilege for that tag (someone who has earned a lot of reputation from that tag). In this case, the question is not a great one; so even if it's not a duplicate, they might have closed it because it... stinks.  That wasn't the right move; but I understand the thought process behind it.

Comment: Ugh, [regex] is a bottomless pit of send-me-teh-codez questions.  Could you not at least have tried *something* and describe what went wrong?  That tutorial gives you the *something*.

Comment: @HansPassant I did of course try something, I even described the context to make it clear why I was looking specifically for a regex answer. The problem with regex is that its pattern matching, not programming. I didn't know that negative-lookaheads could be used in this manner, what on earth could I have said I tried that would have been useful? (what I **did** try was a bunch of stuff with the `[^foo]` negation pattern but I tried it enough to understand that it was the wrong direction entirely)

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Looking at the [first version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33960787/1) of your question, I can see exactly why it was closed. You may have worked for hours trying to solve the problem on your end, but there is *zero indication* of that in your question. It is just like the hundreds of other "*I need to match a pattern with these parameters - gimme teh regex*" questions that pollute the tag every day. Just saying what you said in your last comment would have made a world of difference, but we can't read your mind.